# SQL joining with empty table with "Not Equal To" operator

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables T1 and T2

T1 with columns id & data

T2 with columns id & T1_id

i wanna join T1.id with T2.T1_id

i want all records of T1 whose id is not present in T2
ie, T1.id <> T2.T1_id

so if T2 is empty all records of T1 should be fetched

The problem is

1. if i use LEFT join den all records of T1 id being fetched even if
   the record with corresponding T1_id is present in T2.
2. if i dont use Left join everything is working except when T2 is empty, then no records are fetched

also i would love a linq equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close to what you want. `LEFT JOIN` will suffice and the only missing in your statement is the `WHERE` clause condition.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    T1 a
        LEFT JOIN T2 b
            ON a.ID = b.T1_ID
WHERE   b.T1_ID IS NULL
```

here's the `LINQ` version:

```
var _result = from a in T1
              join b in T2 on a.ID equals b.T1_ID into b_join
              from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where b.T1_ID == null
              select a;
```